# Cannot make an HTTP request between two Laravel Docker containers

Tags: laravel, docker

Let me start off by stating that I know this question has been asked on many forums. I have read them all.

I have two Docker containers that are built with docker-compose and contain a Laravel project each. They are both attached to a network and can ping one another successfully, however, when I make a request from Postman to the one backend that then makes a curl request to the other, I get the connection refused error shown below.

[image]

This is my docker-compose file for each project respectfully:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  bumblebee:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - picknpack
    ports:
      - "8010:8000"
networks:
  picknpack:
    external: true
```

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  optimus:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8020:8000"
    networks:
      - picknpack
    depends_on:
      - optimus_db

  optimus_db:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: optimus
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "33020:3306"
networks:
  picknpack:
    external: true
```

Here you can see the successful ping:
[image]

I would love to keep messing with configuration files but I have a deadline to meet and nothing is working, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Please see inspection of network:
[image]

Comment: connection refused on port 80. your port mappings okay?

Comment: I haven't done anything to map the ports within the docker network but I do have the docker containers' ports mapped to 8020 and 8010 respectfully as per the screenshot above. This is so that I can run the containers at the same time. I don't think this would affect the docker network though.

Comment: Your error indicates that your request is going to port 80. If your port mappings are correct you should be sending requests to either 8010 or 8020. (Also note that normally http port mappings would be `your_port:80` ignore this if yours `(your_port:8000)` is intended)

Comment: Your first error message is unreadable.  Please do not paste screen shots of terminal windows into your questions; include the actual text of the error message or code fragment instead.  How are you actually trying to connect from one service to the other?

Comment: @DavidMaze Please note that you can simply zoom in to read it. I was attempting to connect from one laravel app to another through a curl request as stated in my original post.

Comment: I don't see a `curl` command or a URL anywhere in the text you've included.  What URL are you trying to connect to?  From where (the host, another container, a different host entirely)?

Comment: "I make a request from Postman to the one backend that then makes a curl request to the other". So one container is trying to reach the other after I make a request to one of them through postman. It is doing this through a curl request(which works fine), and the URL can be seen in the image I shared in my post.

Comment: What is your Laravel code? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the docker network that I created, both containers are exposed on port 8000 as per their Dockerfiles. It was looking at me square in the face: 'Connection refused on port 80'. The HTTP client was using that as default rather than 8000. I updated the curl request to hit port 8000 and it works now. Thanks to @user3532758 for your help. Note that the containers are mapped to ports 8010 and 8020 in the external local network, not within the docker network. There they are both served on port 8000 with different IPs